# mysql group by dates and null values

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql because I would like to group by some dates and some null values but the result wasn't the expected. My target is reducing the number of rows of the table but not the number of dates.

The starting table is that one:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| Col1 |        Date1        |        Date2        |        Date3        |  |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| A    | NULL                | 2016-10-27 16:27:22 | NULL                |  |
| A    | NULL                | NULL                | 2012-10-11 07:07:32 |  |
| B    | NULL                | 2016-01-27 16:27:22 | NULL                |  |
| B    | 2016-10-17 16:07:32 | NULL                | NULL                |  |
| C    | NULL                | 2014-10-17 16:07:32 | 2011-10-17 16:57:32 |  |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

I would like to group this table by Col1 to obtain the following output:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Col1 |        Date1        |        Date2        |        Date3        |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| A    | NULL                | 2016-10-27 16:27:22 | 2012-10-11 07:07:32 |
| B    | 2016-10-17 16:07:32 | 2016-01-27 16:27:22 | NULL                |
| C    | NULL                | 2014-10-17 16:07:32 | 2011-10-17 16:57:32 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried with the following query but it didn't work as expected::

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
GROUP BY Col1
```

Can someone help me fixing the query?

Comment: if two rows have the same value in Col1 and different dates in for example Date2, which Date should be returned?

Comment: @martin nice comment... it should be better in that case to return the "newest date"... for example it should be better to return a date with the year 2017 than a date with the year 2015.

Comment: then the answer by Stefano Zanini seems perfect for your use-case :-)

Answer (score 1):

When grouping, you should apply an aggregation function to all the columns that you want to select but are not in the `group by`.
This is not mandatory in the latest versions of MySQL, but in a vast majority of cases it's what you need.

This query should give you the desired output for the sample input you provided, but you may need different aggregation functions if the input is different.

```
SELECT  Col1, max(Date1), max(Date2), max(Date3)
FROM    table1
GROUP BY Col1
```